# Magento 2 with only build in cache (no varnish)

Tags: magento2

I want to switch to magento 2 but my current web hoster doesn't have varnish and implements redis in q4 of this year.

When i upgrade to some more resources, only with the default build in cache (no varnish), do i get a least the same performance like my 1.9.3.2 installation?

And is redis better than varnish? Or do i really need varnish for optimal performance?

Answer (score 1):

Varnish cache is 10x times faster and it differs from Redis. but you dont need it if your shop is not really busy. If your current shop works ok now, then Magento 2 shop will work the same and maybe better.

If you can use Redis for cache storage then its enough to make your M2 shop faster than M1.

M2 cache system is much more advanced than M1.

But SSD drive can easily replace Redis too.

Comment: sure it will work even better.

Comment: And to make it complete, together with nigx i also can use ssl